# sqlite 3 get results from query

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm very new to learning python and now i have to do this assignment which uses the import sqlite3. I need to get all orders from this fictional webshop from the year 2014.

here's what i got so far:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("C:/path/webstore.db")
print('connection succesfull')
cur = db.cursor()
query = '''SELECT b.Besteldatum, k.Achternaam, B.Aantal, a.Prijs 
FROM Bestellingen as b, klanten as k, Bestelregels as B, Artikelen as a
WHERE Besteldatum > 2014 AND Besteldatum < 2015;'''

cur.execute(query)
fe = cur.fetchall()
for i in fe:
    print(i)
```

But instead of printing every result once, the program prints every result about 50 times with different  values in the end. See example below:

```
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 17.5)
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 19.5)
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 17.5)
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 17.5)
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 14.95)
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 14.95)
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 24.95)
('2014-11-06 23:20:00', 'Harmsen', 2, 4.95)
```

this is just a small part of all the printed results, but you get the idea.
does anyone know why this doesn't work the way i want it to?
please, I've been stuck on this for days

Comment: If you run the same SQL query directly on the DB (not through Python) what values do you get? You're not doing a JOIN and you are selecting from multiple tables, this is why you're getting the results described.

Comment: @DustinR is there any way you can maybe show me how? i get the same values when when i directly type into the db. Please, I suck too much at this to know what to do.

Comment: I would have to see your database schema in order to be able to guess at what query you hope to achieve, but even then I might guess wrong. Try a good tutorial on SQL, especially JOIN operations.